# How to view all the matching paragraphs in the web page in the search engine?

Tags: google-search, search, search-engine

Not all search tasks are easy, sometimes several keywords need to be used to describe, and many web pages are very long, so many times there is no desired content in the title and abstract, so you have to click in one by one and search again in the page. If there are many keywords, it will be very troublesome, which is unnecessary and repetitive.

Is there any way to directly display all the matching content in a web page? This saves the trouble of searching in the page and flipping around. The slightly reliable local search function has a list of search results, which can locate each matching place, or even directly view the context, such as visual studio code, PDF xchange editor, and filelocator But does a search engine like Google Bing have such a function?

If not, is there any other way to achieve it?

I know that sometimes search engines can provide highlighted services, but not all pages have them, and the efficiency of using them is still far behind that of listing the results directly. I went to Google to search for relevant keywords, but I didn't find any more clues at present.

So I can only come here for help.

[image]

Comment: Removed [tag:google] as it's already tagged [tag:google-search]. This question looks to be asking for a software recommendation. Besides that it doesn't include details, this type of question belongs to [softwarerecs.se].